# Arm Simulator (URDF) Compatability with new (SDF)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, simulation, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will the ARM Simulator (http://thearmrobot.com/trac/wiki/WikiStart) still work in the NEW Fuerte Gazebo SDF (Simulation Description Format)format?
If not, what would I need to do to get it to work?.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35528/arm-simulator-(urdf)-compatability-with-new-(sdf)/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@TurtleBot_Fan: I initially tried to install the Darpa ARM simulator under Fuerte but had much bigger problems with dependencies and outdated packages.
If you use the recommended platform to install the simulator, there is still a few minor things you need to fix:
http://answers.ros.org/question/37167/guide-how-to-install-the-darpa-arm-simulator/

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0